# Reseting the height of a select HTML

Tags: html

I have a  tag that populates its values based on a click of one of 27 buttons representing alphabetic sorting of one large dataset. I wish to change the size of the select if there are not enough elements but this code is not responding well. If i click on a button that loads say more than 1 element it will change size once and then stay at that size.

```
function AfterAlphabetClick() {
    if (document.getElementById("DataCalls/Data/Indicator").options.length > 1) {
        document.getElementById("DataCalls/Data/Indicator").style.height = "400px;"

    } else {
        document.getElementById("DataCalls/Data/Indicator").style.height = "25px";
    }
}
```

Comment: The logic here is entirely based on the number of options in the element with id `DataCalls/Data/Indicator`. If it has more than one element, then it will attempt to resize itself to 400px. It only calls the other branch if the options length is 0 or 1.

Comment: @ManoDestra When I call the method with 0 elements at 400px it does not change to 25px that is the issue.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. I see the error now regarding using options.length rather than simply length on your select element. Glad you got it resolved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using

```
    document.getElementById("DataCalls/Data/Indicator").length
```

in your condition rather than

```
    document.getElementById("DataCalls/Data/Indicator").options.length
```

if your HTML select has an ID of "DataCalls/Data/Indicator"

Comment: is options not the array of options?

Comment: Yes it is. Using length on the select is just cleaner.

Comment: It looks like your error is actually on the style.height = "400px;". If you take out the semi-colon from inside the quotes, the code should work correctly. Similar to how you have "25px"